# Python beginner :TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable : how to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, extract

Good morning,

I am trying to extract sentences referring to review and their label in an xml file. The problem, I am encountering is that, It is not all the sentences that have a label, so I am extracting only the sentences which have a label and then I return two values : the review and the label. For a strange reason, I keep getting this error :

```
Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations, on en a mis. Avant 75, il suffit d'en mettre et on fait tout de suite de grosses économies. motivation
Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations, on en a mis. Avant 75, il suffit d'en mettre et on fait tout de suite de grosses économies. motivation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flue/extract_split_cls_c.py", line 164, in <module>
    main()
  File "flue/extract_split_cls_c.py", line 87, in main
    review_text, label = get_review_labels(text, category=category, do_lower=args.do_lower)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

When printing the label and review extracted , the terminal display all the sentences with their labels but when I want to return the label and review as values and assign them a variable, the error mentionned above appears. Is it because , there are some sentences which do not have a label and the system does not know what to do  even when I am specifiying in the script that i only want the sentences with the label ?

Here is the script :

```
import os
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import re
import csv
import argparse
import sys

from lxml import etree

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from tools.clean_text import cleaner
from xlm.utils import bool_flag


def review_extractor(text, category='verbatim', do_lower=False):
    """
    Extract review and label
    """

    tree = etree.fromstring(bytes(text, encoding='utf-8'))
    for e in tree.findall(".//*[@fmc]"):
      label = e.xpath("./@fmc")[0]
      for c in e.findall("./part"):
        # print value of "fmc" attribute and text of child element
        print(c.text, label)
        #print(f"{label:15}{c.text}")
        return c.text, label


def get_review_labels(text, category='verbatim', do_lower=False):
    """
    Input: line
    Returns cleaned review and label
    """
    review_text, label = review_extractor(text, category=category, do_lower=do_lower)
    #review_text = cleaner(review_text, rm_new_lines=True)
    print(review_text, label)
    return review_text, label


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--indir', type=str, help='Path to raw data directory.')
    parser.add_argument('--outdir', type=str, help='Path to processed data directory.')
    parser.add_argument('--do_lower', type=bool_flag, default='False', help='True if do lower case, False otherwise.')
    parser.add_argument('--val_ratio', type=float, default=0.2, help='Ratio to split data for validation.')
    parser.add_argument('--use_hugging_face', type=bool_flag, default='False', help='Prepare data to run fine-tuning using \
                                                                                    Hugging Face Transformer library')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    indir = os.path.expanduser(args.indir)
    outdir = os.path.expanduser(args.outdir)

    category = 'verbatim'
    lang = 'fr'
    val_ratio = args.val_ratio

    train_fname = 'train.tsv' if args.use_hugging_face else 'train_0.tsv' 
    val_fname = 'dev.tsv' if args.use_hugging_face else 'valid_0.tsv' 
    test_fname = 'test.tsv' if args.use_hugging_face else 'test_0.tsv'  

    #for category in categories:
    #print('-'*20)
    path = os.path.join(indir, lang, category)
    splts = ['train', 'test']

    for s in splts:
        review_texts = []
        labels = []
        stats = []


        with open(os.path.join(path, s+'.review'), 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f_in:
            next(f_in)
            text = f_in.read()
            print(text) # to display whole file


            review_text, label = get_review_labels(text, category=category, do_lower=args.do_lower)
            #review_text, label = review_extractor(text, category=category, do_lower=args.do_lower) 
            review_texts.append(review_text)
            labels.append(label)
            stats.append(len(review_text.split()))



        #assert len(review_texts) == len(labels) == i


        out_path = os.path.join(outdir, category)
        if not os.path.exists(out_path):
            os.makedirs(out_path)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the file looks like this (there are two files : test and train) but the format is the same :

```
<corpus><verbatim id="15" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Dans le cadre du projet GOSPELS, on a un système équivalent, avec des alertes qui clig                     notent quand la température ou les consommations dérivent, c'est quelque chose qui devrait être de base mais qui re                     ste encore à généraliser.</part></verbatim>

<verbatim id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" origine="IW" type="discours">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro. Vous faites varier la ventillation,                      etc. nous on n'a pas ces équipements là. Piloter les équipements avec un outil dédié.
</part>
</verbatim>

<verbatim id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motivation">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations, on en a                      mis. Avant 75, il suffit d'en mettre et on fait tout de suite de grosses économies.</part>
</verbatim>

<verbatim id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace                      un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK. Mais le deuxième, si c'est un mur extérieur, est ce qu'il est posé directe                     ment sur le mur ? ça veut dire qu'il doit être esthétiquement intégrable du point de vue architectural mais aussi q                     u'il résiste à tous les éléments extérieurs : la pluie, la neige, etc.
</part></verbatim>

<verbatim id="55" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.1" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motivation                     ">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le concept d'alarmes est pas mal, il faut voir comment c'est géré mais c'est pas mal.
</part>
</verbatim>

<verbatim id="68" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
<part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">« intéressant » mais intéressant pour le petit pourcentage de cas ou pour objectiver u                     ne situation. Mais on pourrait imaginer un truc qu'on colle, on pianote un truc et… 'oula, U=0,272'et là il va dire                      'il est sérieux', même si c'est du flan.
</part></verbatim>

        <verbatim id="69" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">ROI, 5 à 10 ans. Si l'énergie explose, ça deviendra rentable de mettre                      l'isolant. Dans les bâtiments où il n'y en a pas, on bataille parce que ça a un coût. Mais pour les bâtiments plus                      récents et qu'on récupère 100€ par an, ce n'est pas suffisant parce qu'on ne récupère jamais les 3000€ d'investiss                     ements.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="80" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW03_0">La caractériser en amont, je vois bien, la suivre dans le temps, j'ai                      du mal à voir si ça a une vraie pertinence. Comme ça, ça me parait bizarre que la performance change dans le temps.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="93" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW05_0">Dans le cadre d'opérations, on pourrait l'utiliser pour des procédés q                     u'on maitrise mal ou des matériaux comme le bois avec un isolant qui peut prendre l'humidité ou des choses comme ça                     .
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="134" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="2.4" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="m                     otivation">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW03_0">On est souvent assez loin des objectifs qu'on se fixe et si au départ                      on n'est pas bon dans les hypothèses qu'on a pu prendre, forcément ça va se retrouver derrière. On peut être plus p                     récis dans l'approche du bâtiment.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="147" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW08_0">La performance se situe dans le choix du verre, dans les joints de cal                     feutrement mais aussi dans le joint entre l'ouvrant et le dormant. Et votre boitier ne mesure pas ça. Dans le temps                     , ce sont ces dispositifs qui se dégradent ; bien plus vite que la paroi.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="160" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="cond                     ition">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW03_0">Suivre la performance dans le temps m'intéresse mais j'ai des indicate                     urs simples, c'est la consommation d'une chaufferie. Si la consommation augmente, c'est qu'il y a un problème. C'es                     t soit lié à la froidure, soit à l'usage des locataires, soit à une mauvaise maitrise des équipements ou… C'est moi                     ns lié à la performance d'une enveloppe parce que je ne vois pas comment l'enveloppe peut perdre de sa performance                      mais peut-être que je me trompe.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="171" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="cond                     ition">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Dans le cadre d'un diagnostic plus large, si l'équipement est proposé                      par le prestataire et que le matériau est plus performant, ça peut être utile. On n'a pas toujours la performance d                     e la paroi.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
        <verbatim id="224" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="moti                     vation">
                <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">tu poses les blocs et tu as directement la performance de ton envelopp                     e. Ça permet de se dire tout de suite si l'isolant est complètement affaissé, s'il est encore performant ou plus du                      tout. Donc ça peut permettre de préconiser un remplacement, un changement ou la conservation pendant encore plusie                     urs années.
                </part>
        </verbatim>
</corpus>
```

As you can see some couple of tag, do not have an attribute "fmc".

What I expected it the function to return the review and label in the variable created toward the end of the script, so that I will be able write them out in a tsv file and count the number of sentences per label. but since I get that error I could not move forward to writing the script. I hope the example can be reproductible.

Comment: `NoneType is not iterable` means you get `None` in some place and you try to do `None[index]`. Probably in line `xpath(...)[0]` you get `None` from `xpath()` and you have `None[0]`. You should check xpath before you get `[0]` - ie. `result = xpath(...)` `if result: result = result[0]`

Comment: I tried inserting the line to check value but after that what I am supposed  to do, I just add my following code , it is printing only two sentences in the terminal the file has more than 5 sentences which have a label (fmc)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in

```
label = e.xpath("./@fmc")[0]
```

If there is no `fmc` then you get

```
label = None[0]
```

and you have error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

You should check value before you get `[0]` - like this

```
label = e.xpath("./@fmc")
if label:
   label = label[0]
else:
   label = "some default label"
```

Comment: Or use `e.get("fmc", "some default label")`.

Comment: using your solution just print two sentences and not all the sentences : def review_extractor(text, category='verbatim', do_lower=False):
    """
    Extract review and label
    """

    tree = etree.fromstring(bytes(text, encoding='utf-8'))
    for e in tree.findall(".//*[@fmc]"):
      label = e.xpath("./@fmc") 
      if label:
        label == label[0] 
      else:
        label = "some default label"
      
      for c in e.findall("./part"):
        print(c.text, label)
        return c.text, label

Comment: my answer resolves problem with error. Now you have different problem which has nothing to do with problem describted in question - you have different mistake in code. As for me your problem is `return` inside `for`-loop in `review_extractor` - so you exit loop after first element and you never get other elemens. You should create list with all results and and use `return` outside loop - `return list_with_all values`

Comment: I understand what I you say but in my case I have the function cleaner which take as input text and not class type list so if I am create a list of all my review and all my label, that function will yield me an error, is there not another way to return uniquely text and not list of text(review) ??

Comment: if you have many unique text then you have to create list with all unique items. And use for-loop to work with them. Using `return c.text, label` inside `for`-loop you get only first unique item. Using `return c.text, label` after `for`-loop you get inly last item. You have to get put all in list and return list. And later use `for`-loop two work with this. Standard rule: if you have many items then somewhere you will have to use list to keep it and `for`-loop to work with items.

Comment: eventually you can use `yield` in `review_extractor` to return single item but then you will have to use `for`-loop inside `get_review_labels` to run `review_extractor` many times and create this list in `get_review_labels` - so you only move problem from `review_extractor` to `get_review_labels`